# Segmented Sieve of Eratasthones Implementation: Incorrect for certain segment sizes

Tags: python, math, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have written an implementation of the Sieve of Eratasthones and the segmented sieve. However, for certain segment sizes, the segmented sieve does not agree with the Sieve of Eratasthones. Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/RahulRajkumar/c183dae594a17315aeca86f933df18e6

```
import math

def sieve(n):
    """
    compute all prime numbers in [[1,n]] using a sieve of
    Eratasthones
    (using two optimizations from wikipedia:
        1. remembering that you don't need to search above sqrt(n)
        2. beginning setting values to 0 at i^2
    """
    if isinstance(n,int) and n > 0:
        sieve = [k+1 for k in range(0,n)]
        for i in sieve:
            if i > 1 and i <= math.sqrt(n):
                j = 0
                while (i**2 + j*i) <= len(sieve):
                    sieve[i**2 + j*i - 1] = 0
                    j = j + 1
        # composites are set to 0, 1 is left alone
        sieve = [m for m in sieve if m not in {0,1}]
        return sieve
    else:
        raise ValueError("n must be a positive integer")

def segmented_sieve(n, segment_size):
    """
    Segmented sieve of eratasthones
    Use: pick segment_size <= sqrt(n)
    """
    primes = sieve(segment_size)
    # k is the largest integer such that k * segment_size <= n
    k = n // segment_size
    for i in range(1,k):
        page = [i*segment_size + j for j in range(1, segment_size + 1)]
        minrange = page[0]
        maxrange = page[-1]
        for p in primes:
            if p <= math.sqrt(maxrange):
                minmult = p * math.ceil(minrange / p)
                maxmult = p * math.floor(maxrange / p)
                for m in range(minmult, maxmult + 1, p):
                    try:
                        page[page.index(m)] = 0
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
        page_primes = [m for m in page if m not in {0,1}]
        primes.extend(page_primes)
    return primes
```

Test values:

```
sieve(10000) == segmented_sieve(10000,100) # True
sieve(10000) == segmented_sieve(10000,95) # True
sieve(10000) == segmented_sieve(10000,94) # False
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @itprorh66 there are no images

Comment: You're coming up two short.  In the case of 94, `k` will be 106.  94 * 106 = 9964, so you're not considering any numbers bigger than 9964.  There happen to be two primes between 9964 and 10000.  95 * 105 is 9975, and there are no primes between 9975 and 10000.  You need to handle that last partial segment.